# Already up to date gitlab pipeline stackoverflow

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pipelines

i trying gitlab pipeline. now i make some changes & code pushed in master branch
pipeline showing already update to date but i have changes in code
[image]

I try to pull in three phase but still same issue
*.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
before_script:
  - echo "Before script"
building:
  stage: build
  script:
    - git pull origin master
testing:
  stage: test
  script:
    - git pull origin master
deploying:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

If the gitlab-ci workflow starts by cloning your repository, no amount of git pull will change the fact you *already* have the full history, and, at the time of the workflow, this is "already up to date".

In other words, a git pull would not be needed in your `gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Comment: I pushed changes in master branch & deploy manually . But pipeline showing `already up to date` again and again

Comment: @PirtaMatharu Yes, because it *clones* your repository, thereby getting the very latest of what you have just pushed.

Comment: Can you give me any reference to solve this?

Comment: @PirtaMatharu, in other words, in your screen shot the line 11, has already done the git pull origin master. You do not need to do it again.
Think when running the CI, you are in a full clean docker, one of the first step included by gitlab-ci is to clone the repo. Most of time you never need to do any git command in your CI. You can focus on QA / test / deploy. Don't worry about sources there are here. Try a ls -l to check it.

Comment: @PirtaMatharu Considering a pull just after a clone would almost always give you a "Already up to date", there is no real issue to solve here.

Answer (score 0):

If your pipeline is running on the same repo that you changed, there is no need to use `git pull`. Although, if your pipeline triggers (on repo A) another pipeline on another repository (repo B), to access files in repo A, you have to pull repo A in repo B pipeline.